# Error while trying to use Matplotlib.tri.UniformRefiner.refine_field

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, contour

I was trying to perform a contour refinement task, and using mtri.UniformRefiner.refine_field to do so. The codes are as following:

```
triang = mtri.Triangulation(mesh_pts[:, 0],mesh_pts[:, 1],triangles=tri_revise)
refiner = mtri.UniformTriRefiner(triang)
interpolator = mtri.CubicTriInterpolator(triang,grid_z)
tri_refi, grid_z = refiner.refine_field(grid_z, subdiv=4, triinterpolator=interpolator)
```

When I try to run the above code, an error occured:
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (114,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (109,)

The shape of z value, grid_z, is (114,), but I have a hard time finding out what the indexing result shape is. I was wondering if anyone can help me locate the problem. Or if there is some other way to interpolate triangle_mesh and z values, please point out as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you check the shape of mesh_pts, the shape of triang and grid_z?

Comment: Yep, the shape of mesh_pts matches the shaple of grid_z at 114, and the shape of triang is 198 which shoud not be the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was trying to plot a `tricontour` of x, y and z data. I solved it by dropping duplicate values base on x and y.

`data.sort_values('z').drop_duplicates(subset=['x', 'y'], keep='last')`

data here is a dataframe with columns 'x', 'y' and 'z'.